# VB.NET Copy a file from resource to hard disk

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource

I want to copy a file from my project program resource to hard disk.

I use this code but it says:

```
"Access to the path 'D:\New Folder' is denied."

<code>IO.File.WriteAllText(MyPath, My.Resources.MyFile)</code>
```

But I have administrator rights. Is there any other code to copy a file from resource?

My OS is Win XP Service Pack 3.

Comment: Does that path / Folder already exist?? If not, create it first...

Comment: Check permissions on the folder then.

Comment: "But I have administrator rights" means nothing unless you remember to  explicitly run the process as an administrator.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: +1, and also if admin permissions were specifically revoked for this account under this folder (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

My path was:

```
D:\New Folder
```

but when I changed it to:

```
D:\New Folder\MyFileName.ExtensionName
```

The problem solved.